# print an array of input elements on a page using watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, webdriver, watir-webdriver

I would like to cycle threw all the input elements on a web page and print the name attribute of each. I am having trouble creating the array of elements to cycle threw. here is my code hitting the example page at [bit.ly/watir-webdriver-demo](http://bit.ly/watir-webdriver-demo)

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

b = Watir::Browser.new 
b.goto("bit.ly/watir-webdriver-demo")

listOfInputs = b.form(:method => "post")
listOfInputs.input.each do |i| 
    puts i.Name
end
```

How can I print out the name of each input on the page

Comment: I think you want `inputs` (plural) in the code above, not `input`  input will not return an array or collection, so the .each iterator will not work there.

Answer (score 1):

looks like i just needed to not use form. 
I use the body instead and this works!

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

browser = Watir::Browser.new 
browser.goto("bit.ly/watir-webdriver-demo")

body = browser.body
body.inputs.each do |input| 
  puts input.name  
end
```

Comment: You could have used the form. You just had to change the `:method=>"post"` to `:method=>"POST"` as it is case-sensitive. Alternatively, in case of multiple forms, it might be better to go by `:id=>"ss-form"`.